# Using flask-login with http request

Tags: python, authentication, flask, httprequest, flask-login

I'm trying to implement Flask-Login using an HTTP request to authenticate the credentials. The link I'm using is an IP address with `/login?psName=myUser&psPwd=myPass` -- depending on `psName` and `psPwd`'s values, the page will return an XML:

for incorrect credentials (ie `psName`=`myUser`, `psPwd`=`wrongPassword`):

```
<cache version="1.0">
    <exception version="1.0" code="-777" message="Incorrect Login or Password [myUser]"/>
</cache>
```

for correct credentials (ie `psName`=`myUser`, `psPwd`=`rightPassword`):

```
<cache version="1.0">
    <session_info session_key="1234" full_name="Alice Bob" login="myUser" user_key="4321"/>
</cache>
```

Currently, to check authentication for my `login` method, I capture the login input submitted and store it in a dict `login_info`. I pass `login_info` as the param to a function `authen_user`.

```
def authen_user(login_info):
    r = requests.get('http://10.10.80.111/PDS.sfw/net4/login.jsp', params=login_info)

    root = ElementTree.fromstring(r.content)

    sessionExists=root.find('session_info')

    if sessionExists is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True

@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u = request.form['username']
        p = request.form['password']
        login_info = {'psName': u, 'psPwd': p}

        if authen_user(login_info):
            # if successful login
            return redirect('homepage')
        else:
            # if invalid credentials
            flash('Invalid login.')
            return render_template('login.html', uName=u)
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')
```

Since I want to use Flask-Login to handle the sessions for me, I'm using the `request_loader`. How do I get the captured Username and Password and pass it to `request_loader`? The documentation passes in a single parameter called `request`. Am I allowed to change this? I was thinking of making `login_info` a global variable so that when I update it with the password&username, I can pass the login_info to request_loader. 
Are there other methods?

Really appreciate the help. Thanks!